# Populating a DropDownListFor with values from another model linked by a foreign key?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I'm building a web application for my company. One of my models is an employee model, `employees1`, and it is quite complex. One issue I've run into is inserting values into my `phone_manager` table, which is bound to a `phone_manager` model. The `phone_manager` model has a foreign key relationship with `phone_types`. `Phone_types` contains an entry for every different allowable phone type in the system.

In my employee model create view, I have created an area for users to enter their phone numbers. The phone numbers have 3 fields for the user to populate, `phone_type`, `phone_number`, and `phone_extension`.

What I'm attempting to do is change the editor for phone_type to be a Drop Down List instead of a text box with integer values. The drop down list would grab all the different phone types from the `phone_types` table. The `phone_types` table contains two fields `phone_type_id` and `phone_type_name`.

My condensed model code is as following:

```
[Table("employee.employees")]
public partial class employees1
{

    public employees1()
    {
        employee_phone_manager = new HashSet<phone_manager>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int employee_id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Employee ID")]
    public int? assigned_id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Phone Numbers")]
    public virtual ICollection<phone_manager> employee_phone_manager { get; set; }

    internal void CreatePhoneNumbers(int count = 1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            employee_phone_manager.Add(new phone_manager());
        }
    }

    public virtual ICollection<salary> salaries { get; set; }

    public class internalEmployees
    {
        public employees1 employees1 { get; set; }
        public phone_manager phone_manager { get; set; }
        public phone_types phone_types { get; set; }
    }

    [Table("employee.phone_manager")]
    public partial class phone_manager
    {
        [Key]
        public int phone_id { get; set; }

        public int employee_id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(15)]
        public string phone_number { get; set; }

        [StringLength(5)]
        public string phone_extension { get; set; }

        public int phone_type { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "date")]
        public DateTime date_added { get; set; }

        public bool deleted { get; set; }

        public virtual employees1 employees1 { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("phone_type")]
        public virtual phone_types phone_types { get; set; }
    }

    [Table("employee.phone_types")]
    public partial class phone_types
    {
        public phone_types()
        {
            phone_manager = new HashSet<phone_manager>();
        }

        [Key]
        public int phone_type_id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string phone_type_name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<phone_manager> phone_manager { get; set; }
    }
```

And my controller for create currently is:

```
    // GET: /Employees/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.all_id = new SelectList(db.all_employees, "all_id", "all_id");
        var employee = new employees1();
        employee.CreatePhoneNumbers(2);
        return View(employee);
    }
```

My phone portion of my view is:

```
    <div class="form-group" id="phoneNumbers">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.employee_phone_manager, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.employee_phone_manager)
        </div>
    </div>
```

With the following template:

```
@model AdminPanel.Models.employees1.internalEmployees
<div class="phoneNumber">
<p>
    <label>Phone Number</label>
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.phone_manager.phone_type)
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.phone_manager.phone_number)
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.phone_manager.phone_extension)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.phone_manager.deleted, new { @class = "mark-for-delete" })
</p>
</div>
```

Where I have the editor for `x.phone_manager.phone_type`, I'd like to have a combo box with all the values from `phone_types` instead.

Comment: you need to show to us your attempt of code

Comment: Why another model? I'd expect to see all needed data for a single view to be in a single model (which generally speaking, is tailored to that specific view). Barring any partial views etc. that repeat throughout the application, they can logically have their own model, but it should then be used only in their view (hence 1 model per view).

Comment: @Jorge I have completely rewritten the question with all my current pertinent code. Hopefully it is a bit easier to understand now.

Comment: @Flater I apologize because I haven't ever worked with MVC, but I'm trying to get the hang of it. My `employees1` model contains nearly everything inside a single model, as visible from my above code, but all the other portions are partials that tie back into it.

Comment: There's a different approch to two types of partial views. If the partial views are 'general' (e.g a "Welcome, User1" message.) That's an unrelated partial view and should have its own model. If you have a partialview that is used for displaying the content of this specific view (e.g. if you have a list of items, you could render specific details to an additional partialview. Because that partial view 'belongs' to the view, its model should probably either be the same, or a child of the original view's viewmodel. But this is more good practice rather than the only way to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I found a very handy tutorial on using nested collections to achieve exactly what I was originally after -> http://www.itorian.com/2013/04/nested-collection-models-in-mvc-to-add.html

From there, I managed to retrieve my `phone_types` table as a `SelectList` and pass it over to my `ViewBag` like this:

```
ViewBag.phonetype = new SelectList(db.phone_types, "phone_type_id", "phone_type_name");
```

Then in my view, I added the following:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.phone_type, (SelectList)ViewBag.phonetype, new { @class = "form-control" })
```